# jQuery quizz with radiobuttons misbehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am writing a simple online quizz. There are four radiobuttons as choices. Initially, the script just populates the choices for the first question. After that, user should choose the next one and click the button. If the answer matches the correct one, total increments. Else, next question is loaded. When the 10th question is submitted, results are loaded. Questions are loaded from an array with ten objects called "pitanja". quNo is the question number, opt1 to opt 4 are option texts and corrNo is the correct option number.

**BUT** if user hasn't chosen anything, there is a condition, but it won't work. The quizz just moves on and each time sets the fourth choice. Even if something other is chosen, the next one is still four by default. Maybe that one, too...  Additionally, it always says that success rate is 30%, which corresponds to 3 of 10 correct d's...

I know this is not complex at all, but I'm very confused here... Where have I gone wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pitanja = [{
    "quNo": 1,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 2
  }, {
    "quNo": 2,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 4
  }, {
    "quNo": 3,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 2
  }, {
    "quNo": 4,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 4
  }, {
    "quNo": 5,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 1
  }, {
    "quNo": 6,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 3
  }, {
    "quNo": 7,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 2
  }, {
    "quNo": 8,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 1
  }, {
    "quNo": 9,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 4
  }, {
    "quNo": 10,
    "opt1": "a",
    "opt2": "b",
    "opt3": "c",
    "opt4": "d",
    "corrNo": 3
  }];

  //****************************************************//

  var corrTotal = 0; // total correct answers
  var qNumber = 0; // current question number
  var currentChoice = 0; //current answer choice

  function popuniPitanja(qNumber) {
    var qu = pitanja[qNumber]; //current question, by array index
    $("#quizz-question-no").text("Question " + qu["quNo"]);
    $("#label1").text(qu["opt1"]);
    $("#label2").text(qu["opt2"]);
    $("#label3").text(qu["opt3"]);
    $("#label4").text(qu["opt4"]);
  }

  function proveriOdgovor(choice, corr) { // choice is the selected value, corr is the current question correct value
    if (parseInt(choice) === corr) {
      corrTotal++;
    } //if selected and correct value match, increment total correct
  }

  function sacuvajIzbor() { //save user choice
    if ($("#opt1").prop("checked", true)) {
      currentChoice = 1
    };
    if ($("#opt2").prop("checked", true)) {
      currentChoice = 2
    };
    if ($("#opt3").prop("checked", true)) {
      currentChoice = 3
    };
    if ($("#opt4").prop("checked", true)) {
      currentChoice = 4
    };
  }

  function ucitajRezultate() { // loads quizz results
    var average = corrTotal * 10; // divide by total (10 questions) and multiply by a 100 for percents
    $("#quizz-warn").hide();
    $("#quizz-form").html("Broj tačnih odgovora: " + corrTotal + ", što je: " +
      average + "%"); //erase quizz form and display results
  }

  $("button").click(function() { //handle user submit
    var correctAnswer = pitanja[qNumber]["corrNo"]; //save the number of curent correct answer
    sacuvajIzbor(); //save user choice
    if (currentChoice < 1 || currentChoice > 4) { //if choice isn't 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, user didn't choose at all
      $("#quizz-warn").text("Molimo izaberite odgovor :)"); //warn user to choose an answer
    } else {
      proveriOdgovor(currentChoice, correctAnswer); //check user answer and act accordingly
      if (qNumber === 9) { //if question number is 9, it is 10th question, so display results
        ucitajRezultate(); //display results
      } else { //if it's not, move on to the next question
        popuniPitanja(++qNumber); //load next question
        currentChoice = 0; //reset current choice to 0
      }
    }
  });

  popuniPitanja(qNumber); //initially, load the first question (qNumber is 0 by default)
});
```

```html
<html lang="sr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The quizz</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="quizz-form">
  <span id="quizz-title">Quizz text: </span>
  <p id="quizz-question-no"></p>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="quizz-opt" id="opt1" value="1">
    <label class="opt-txt" for="opt1" id="label1"></label>
    <br>
    <!--option 1 end-->
    <input type="radio" name="quizz-opt" id="opt2" value="2">
    <label class="opt-txt" for="opt2" id="label2"></label>
    <br>
    <!--option 2 end-->
    <input type="radio" name="quizz-opt" id="opt3" value="3">
    <label class="opt-txt" for="opt3" id="label3"></label>
    <br>
    <!--option 3 end-->
    <input type="radio" name="quizz-opt" id="opt4" value="4">
    <label class="opt-txt" for="opt4" id="label4"></label>
    <br>
    <!--option 4 end-->
    <button type="button">Dalje</button>
  </form>
  <div id="quizz-warn"></div>
</div>
<script src="kviz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I know some names are not in English, but I didn't think I would have to seek help, and at this point I'm afraid to change them all :) Hope that comments help...

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dzenesiz/2uxba6sz/

Comment: How come? I use it to populate the questions' text inside the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in your `currentChoice` if statement. You should change it like this:

```
if ($("#opt1").prop("checked")) {
     currentChoice = 1
};
```

instead of

```
if ($("#opt1").prop("checked", true)) {
    currentChoice = 1
};
```

Simply, you were setting all of the options to `checked` `.prop("checked", true)`. Now, it checks the option. If it is selected, `currentChoice` gets updated and your user will not be able to move to the next question without answering current one.

To even make it more functional, you need to remove error message when user choose an option. So I added `$("#quizz-warn").text("Molimo izaberite odgovor :)");` to else-statement of the button click event. In order to reset the options, just add this to the same else-statement:

```
$("input").prop("checked",false);
```

Check it out in [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/56kudwwr/2/)

Comment: Wow, such a small mistake :) seems i didn't fully understand the syntax... could you, maybe, tell me how to reset the radios? The way you fixed it, it somehow stays on that choice for the next question too...

Comment: I updated the answer and jsfiddle to address the new issue. now it will reset all of options after successful moving to the next question.